# Não consigo resolver uma linha de notificação

Tags: java, android, xml

> O erro está na linha: notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);. Não consegui resolver isso. Qualquer alteração que eu faça dá erro.

```
// Define Notification's message and Intent
    CharSequence contentTitle = context.getString(R.string.notif_title);
    CharSequence contentText = String.format(context.getString(R.string.notif_text),
            iptext);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, FTP_Start_Stop.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Comment: Posta seu código.

Comment: Onde vc está inicializando o `notification`?

Comment: @RodrigoPaixão ServerRunningNotification.java, eu preciso modificar essa parte, mas não sei como fazer isso. Sigo os exemplos, e dá erro.

Comment: Qual erro? Quais exemplos?